# Docker, python, work with multiple dockers simultaneously, like building blocks

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Is it possible to work with multiple docker images or containers simultaneously, like building blocks?

For example:

- I've 1 docker file, which can be used as a stand alone thing. What it does is: (python) It receives an input (python flask), uses a python script to modify the input and gives an output back (POST).
- What I would like to have is. That I can create another, docker which can use the utilities from my first docker. In such a way, that I actually work with building blocks. "Ah, i need this, i'll plug in X, and then i can use its stuff". (a bit like object oriented programming but then with +/- containers)
- Thus, if I'm creating a python project for docker C, I would like to call other containers which are running, and use their functionalities.

[ Doing a curl or post request, looks for me a bit devious, because you've all the up and running containers in the same environment, thus, i'm wondering, if you just doesn't can call them, instead of ... ]

kind regards

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a microservice architecture. If your services expose a http api, you can use that to communicate between services running in different docker containers. If that's what you're after, here's a pretty good article about microservices with python. http://www.fullstackpython.com/microservices.html

Comment: How much do you know about [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?